# How to change from Gitlab to Bucket

Tags: gitlab, bucket

I worked on gitlab, anf now I want to work with Bucket. I couldn't clone the bucket, I don't wanna use Gitlab anymore, so what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about changing source control systems, just delete your Gitlab account and open Bucket and upload it to Bucket.

Comment: How can I can delete my Gitlab plz!